# Как задавать и убирать data атрибут на input[type=radio] в зависимости от :checked

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно чтобы при выборе `radio` добавлялся атрибут `data-checked`, а при изменении выбора - убирался и переставлялся на другой вариант. У меня вышло сделать так, что атрибут ставится, но не выходит сделать удаление. Решение должно быть на чистом JS. Заранее спасибо)

Использую примерно такой код:

```js
form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const target = e.target;

  if (target.checked) {
    target.parentElement.setAttribute('data-checked', 'true');
  } else {
    target.parentElement.removeAttribute('data-checked', 'true');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="survey__item_answer --age js-input-radio">
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id1">
    <label for="id1" class="survey__item_label">Under 18</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id2">
    <label for="id2" class="survey__item_label">18-24</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id3">
    <label for="id3" class="survey__item_label">25-34</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id4">
    <label for="id4" class="survey__item_label">35-44</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы удалить атрибут у элемент c `data-checked` нужно просто обратиться к нему `document.querySelector('[data-checked]')`. А после этого назначить этот атрибут на `target`

```js
let form = document.querySelector('.form');
form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  if (target.checked) {
  let parent = target.closest('.js-input-radio');
  parent.querySelector('[data-checked]')?.removeAttribute('data-checked');
    target.parentElement.setAttribute('data-checked', 'true');  
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="survey__item_answer --age js-input-radio form">
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id1">
    <label for="id1" class="survey__item_label">Under 18</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id2">
    <label for="id2" class="survey__item_label">18-24</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id3">
    <label for="id3" class="survey__item_label">25-34</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id4">
    <label for="id4" class="survey__item_label">35-44</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `нужно просто обратиться к нему`, но обратитесь к первому на странице, а что если в других местах до данного кода уже есть `data-checked`, он удалится, а в данном коде так и останется. Зачем `target.parentElement`, если в любом случае вернётся `input` т.е. change на нём отработает.. не?

Comment: Есть конкретный код с конкретным примером. Можно добавить cloeset(). не страшно

Comment: Да, но сами же знаете, что требуется "минимальный" код для примера, так же понятное дело, что участники SO не должны писать всё за автора вопроса, но как по мне, то автор может получить опять ошибку и снова обратиться с данным кодом. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯, я не докапываюсь, стараюсь по крайней мере, просто хочу уточнить этот момент для всех кто прочитает)

Comment: @De.Minov я понимаю. Поправил.

Comment: Спасибо что прислушались, от меня +)

Comment: по поводу parentElement - я просто не очень понял куда человеку нужно устанавливать этот атрибут. В примере ставится на родительский div. В вопросе на инпут. Подумал, что раз у него только с удалением проблемы, то не буду менять ничего.

Comment: Хм, действительно, не обратил внимание на это

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает)

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.js-input-radio');

form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  
  if(target.type === 'radio') {
    if(target.checked && !target.hasAttribute('data-checked')) {
      target.setAttribute('data-checked', true);
    } else {
      target.removeAttribute('data-checked');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
[data-checked] ~ label {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="survey__item_answer --age js-input-radio">
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id1">
    <label for="id1" class="survey__item_label">Under 18</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id2">
    <label for="id2" class="survey__item_label">18-24</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id3">
    <label for="id3" class="survey__item_label">25-34</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id4">
    <label for="id4" class="survey__item_label">35-44</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Для демо через CSS меняется background у label, если у input есть атрибут `data-checked`.

---

Если требуется, чтобы предыдущий удалялся.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.js-input-radio');

form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  
  if(target.type === 'radio') {
    let old = form.querySelector('input[data-checked="true"]');
    if(old) old.removeAttribute('data-checked');
    target.setAttribute('data-checked', true);
    
  }
});
```

```css
[data-checked] ~ label {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="survey__item_answer --age js-input-radio">
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id1">
    <label for="id1" class="survey__item_label">Under 18</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id2">
    <label for="id2" class="survey__item_label">18-24</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id3">
    <label for="id3" class="survey__item_label">25-34</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id4">
    <label for="id4" class="survey__item_label">35-44</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Если требуется устанавливать атрибут на родителя.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.js-input-radio');

form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  
  if(target.type === 'radio') {
    let old = form.querySelector('.survey__item_variant[data-checked="true"]');
    if(old) old.removeAttribute('data-checked');
    target.closest('.survey__item_variant').setAttribute('data-checked', true);
  }
});
```

```css
.survey__item_variant[data-checked] {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="survey__item_answer --age js-input-radio">
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id1">
    <label for="id1" class="survey__item_label">Under 18</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id2">
    <label for="id2" class="survey__item_label">18-24</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id3">
    <label for="id3" class="survey__item_label">25-34</label>
  </div>
  <div class="survey__item_variant">
    <input name="age" type="radio" class="survey__item_input --radio" id="id4">
    <label for="id4" class="survey__item_label">35-44</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Взаимно плюсик )